# How to parse <link> tags to proper <a> tags?

Tags: php, typo3

I have textblocks which look something like this:

```
$message ='<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <link http://some/website.html _blank external-link-new-window "Opens external link in new window">here</link> Lorem <link foo@bar.com - mail "Opens window for sending email"><div>'
```

Now I need to parse those link tags to proper a tags in pure php. I've tried with regexes so far but didnt achieve much. I know these function exists in the typo3 core in this class right here: [Link](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/_rte_html_parser_8php_source.html)
Any suggestions how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Simply run it through the parsefunc_RTE, try this snippet:

```
 $message = ...
 $parseFuncConf = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup['lib.']['parseFunc_RTE.'];
 $messageHtml = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->cObj->parseFunc($message, $parseFuncConf);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you output this message to fluid template, you maybe can use  around it. Guess it should parse the link.
In PHP you probably can use a function of the ContentObjectRenderer like this one: https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_frontend_1_1_content_object_1_1_content_object_renderer.html#a1f5083b23f8f4a6cb6c26a3f6807bb37